# backpack for laravel segment missing during upload

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I created a CRUD (using backpack crud for laravel )for uploading certificates, when i upload the pdf I use

```
 $this->crud->addField([

      'name'  => 'respaldo',
      'label' => 'Respaldo',
      'type'  => 'upload',
      'upload' => true,

      'wrapperAttributes' => [
            'class' => 'form-group col-md-6'
       ],
    ]);
```

when i want to see the link of the uploaded file, storage is missing from the route so i added it to a mutator ,see below

```
 public function setRespaldoAttribute($value)
 {   

  $attribute_name = "respaldo";
  $disk = "public";
  $destination_path = "uploads/respaldos";
  $this->uploadFileToDisk($value, $attribute_name, $disk,   $destination_path);
 }    

 public function getRespaldoLink() {

 return '<a href="'.asset('storage/'.$this->respaldo).'" target="_blank">
             Descargar</a>';
 }
```

Now when clicking on the link it's displayed on the listview, the problem is when i click on edit , "storage" segment is missing there so i get 404 instead. see image

[image]

Comment: Hi Rodrigo. Is the file uploaded on the disk? If so, it must be a link issue. I'd recommend you take a look at the disk you are using inside the filesystems.php - if it is public. How about if you try the "uploads" disk, and change the destination path accordingly?

Comment: i use "uploads" now , and only "respaldo" folder, the file saves in (public/uploads/respaldo/) , the path is saved as respaldos/276e91a4550ddb4982405286148181e4.pdf   on DB, i have to use -><a href="'.asset('uploads/'.$this->respaldo).'" target="_blank"> to show the link on listview, on edit the same , uploads is missing from the route, can't find a way to prefix uploads .

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and tried to amend the link before displaying it on browser for user to preview in Update or Show CRUD.

The issue is whatever the path is stored inside your database, it will pop up on browser without the head folder. As we know, we can amend the head folder with Laravel LIKE asset('storage/'.$file_path)

So, you need to update the path before storing into database.

1. Search and Update file HasUploadFields.php
2. Update this line with add-on 'storage/' Like this:
   $this->attributes[$attribute_name] = 'storage/' . $file_path;
3. Do same for uploadMultipleFilesToDisk method
4. Now for all new file uploaded, it will add-on 'storage/' before stored file path